# Avoiding circular references between a models project and a contracts project

Tags: c#, asp.net

This isn't a novel question ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081070/asp-net-mvc-how-to-avoid-circular-reference-between-2-projects)), but I'd like to make an attempt at asking the question more succinctly to elicit a better response.

I'm currently working on a WCF application with a co-worker and we've separated our code into separate projects. Our structure looks like this:

[image]

Each collapsed folder follows the above convention.

**The problem**

The circular reference problem occurs between the **.Models** projects and our **.Contracts** projects since an interface often references a model and visa versa.

I'll demonstrate what I mean with a simple example.

**For Example**

In the example below I created two very simple projects. One project for the *models* and one for the *interfaces*.

[image]

Starting with a type that models an common object for us, for example:

```
namespace Example.Models
{
    public class MyType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
} // project 1
```

Then we often make another object that contains a list of that type:

```
namespace Example.Models
{
    public class AnotherType : ISomeInterface // let's add an interface!
    {
        public List<MyType> MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
} // project 1
```

This works just fine until we decide to wire up an interface for this `AnotherType` class in our other project.

```
namespace Example.Contracts
{
    interface ISomeContract
    {   
        List<MyType> MyProperty { get; set; } 
    }
} // project 2
```

Obviously, in order to add `MyType` to our **Example.Contracts** project, we need to add a reference to our **Example.Models** project. Conversely, in order to add `ISomeContract` to our `AnotherType` class we need to add a reference to the **Example.Contracts** project.

So we've got ourselves a circular reference.

### My Question

In the given scenario, is there a conventional way to avoid this circular reference issue? Or is this flawed by design?

Here's the simple [Example project](http://beaulieu.blob.core.windows.net/images/General/20160513151026Example.Contracts.zip.zip) for anyone interested

Comment: "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection... Except for the problem of too many layers of indirection." Normally, my pure data models have no behavior and need no interface. As such, my contracts can reference such a model project freely, and there is no dependency the other direction. Think in terms of a entity model project, a contract project, and a repositories project. The repositories fulfill contracts and work with models, and another, separate business logic project depends on the contracts (and gets injected with the repositories).

Comment: Maybe you could just Template the interface so there is only one direction of dependancy, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344694/implement-an-interface-with-generic-methods
Or try using dependancy injection like 'Autofac' http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you cannot use the interfaces without also using the models. `ISomeInterface` requires a reference to the assembly containing `MyType`. But some of those models also reference the interfaces.

If any interfaces and models reference each other than they are both part of the same "interface." Not "interface" as in the keyword, but they are part of the contract defined by your interfaces. It helps if you think of them that way. The models and interfaces together define your contract.

When you look at it that way, it becomes clear that those models and interfaces belong in the same assembly. It's especially clear because neither can exist without the other.

In practice, I use one assembly that contains the contract for my WCF services - the interfaces for the services themselves and any objects they will return. Then the WCF service references that contract assembly and implements it. Consumers reference that same contract, and then for convenience I use [Castle Windsor's WCF facility](https://pollyshaw.wordpress.com/2013/07/28/my-recipe-for-wcf-part-2-using-castle-windsor-to-set-up-the-connections/) to create WCF proxies. Added bonuses - now you can use dependency injection, you don't have to create proxies, and you don't have to worry about closing/disposing them.

[Here's a link](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/04/13/wcf-dependency-injection-in-5-minutes.html) also on using Windsor in the WCF service itself.

Comment: This is one direction I've been considering. Though what if you have contacts that are common throughout multiple different projects? Should I rewrite the contract for the other project? I wouldn't want to pull in modes from a different project. Thanks

Comment: For example, in the top picture you see a folder for MobileApp, Membership, Logging... I also have one named Core which contains classes and contracts available through the entire solution. I like being able to include contracts from Core into my other projects.

Comment: You can create a "common" contract for elements reused between services. In practice I find this is more models than interfaces, since interfaces are implemented by specific services. Then you can reference that common assembly from your contract assembly and anything that uses it.

Comment: I like that. Let me consider this for a while before I accept an answer. Thanks for taking the time to respond, I've up voted.